# Mongoose return only one element from document's nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to fetch a *single* element within an array in my document, without fetching the whole array itself. Is that possible to do using Mongoose?

I've tried using *dot.notation* but it doesn't seem to work 
 - It just fetches empty nested objects after the "index dot"

```
  // Here I'd like to get 
  // The first undo-ed item from the first board within my `boardBucket`

  Room.findOne({name: this.name}, `boardBucket.items.0.undoedItems.1`, (err, result)=> {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
  })
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

#### Reasons I'd like to avoid fetching the whole array

- My objects are quite large and would result in memory issues if I fetched them back in their entirety
- It's inefficient however one looks at it.

Here's my `Schema` in case it helps:

```
var roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    boardBucket: {
      currentBoardId: String,
      items: [
        {
          boardId: String,
          boardItems: Array,
          undoedItems: Array, // <- Need to get a *single* element from this array
          viewPosition: String
        }
      ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

you can use `slice` funtionality of `query` provided by mongoose. Go through [mongoose documentation on slice](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-slice) for better understanding.

> According to the documentation:
>
> ```
> slice([path], val)
> ```
>
> Specifies a $slice projection for an array.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> [path] <String>
> val <Number> number/range of elements to slice
> ```

**Try this for your problem, i hope it works:**

```
Room.findOne({name: this.name})
    .slice('boardBucket.items', 1)
    .slice('boardBucket.items.undoedItems', [1,1])
    .exec()
```

This will return the first element of the `items` array, and the second of `undoedItems`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not the downvoter - However what you posted wouldn't work with **nested** arrays

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides This actually will do what you want if you chain a _second_ `slice` call to what ravi shows of `.slice('boardBucket.items.undoedItems', [1,1])`. That way both array levels are sliced.

Comment: I will update the answer according to @JohnnyHK suggestion. i didnt look for the first item in `undoedItem` .I just looked for first item in `items`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK does the slice chaining fetch *only* the item I'm after? Fetch here meaning from the mongoDB server my db runs to my server that calls `find()` - Or does mongoose fetch the whole doc but just return me the sliced-sliced item?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Yes, the slice filtering is done server-side. The query gets translated to the following when sent to the server: `rooms.findOne({}) { fields: { 'boardBucket.items': { '$slice': 1 }, 'boardBucket.items.undoedItems': { '$slice': [ 1, 1 ] } } }`